Office 365 Graph connector vs custom plugin which one should be used for FileSystem Application
We have an on-premise file system product. You can think of like Dropbox that runs on-premise. Our users have their own files, and they can also share these files with other users within the organization. Additionally, there are shared folders where different users have different access permissions.
We want to integrate the files in our product with Microsoft 365, taking into account the permission mechanism within our product. In other words, we want company's employees to get answers from Copilot based on the company's data when they ask a question, but we also want to ensure that users who do not have permission do not receive answers from files they don't have access to. This means that each user should get responses from Copilot within the scope of their permissions.
As far as I understand, there are two methods to achieve this. The first is to use a Graph Connector, and the other is to write a plugin. Which method do you think is more appropriate for our scenario, and which one should we focus on? If you received such a requirement, how would you proceed?

Always think in this way. If you have start 2 way communication with the biz applications then you should go for plugin. Say you want create a copilot for logging incidents, update comments to incidents or check the status of the real time data.
But if you just want to consume only the data like read the files from the file system or content management system then graph connector is a wise choice.
Solution for your scenario: you can get the content from file system via REST API and store it in graph db along with the permissions (MS Graph has provisions for access control list or also called as ACL to maintain permissions to the content connected with Entra id) and feed this as copilot knowledge source.
